# Making a public function for a MS Access query

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good day all, I need some help in making a function to return values in a payroll query. The following is my current design.

```
Table Name: Tax
Fields: EffDate(mm/dd/yyyy), Allowance, HSurcharge, NISAllowance, TaxRate.

In the order above this is the current records:
1.  9/1/2016,  60000,  8.25,  70%,  25%
2.  1/1/2017,  72000,  8.25,  70%,  25%

Query Name: Payroll
Fields: EmpName, PeriodEnd, Gross, NIS, HSurcharge, PAYE, NetPay

Expected Results as per the order above:
John Doe,  31/3/18,  7000,  70.40,  8.25,  201,  6720.35
Mary Doe,  31/12/16,  7000,  70.40,  8.25,  487,  6434.35
```

The problem is trying to make an expression or a function to calculate PAYE.
Paye = (Gross-(Allowance/12)-(NIS*NISAllowance))*TaxRate

but the PeriodEnd must match the EffDate. For example:

```
9/1/2016 Allowance = $60,000
1/1/2017 Allowance = $72,000 

Paye for 31/12/16 = (Gross-(60000/12)-(NIS*NISAllowance))*TaxRate = 201.
Paye for 31/3/18 = (Gross-(72000/12)-(NIS*NISAllowance))*TaxRate = 487.
```

So any Gross Pay before 1-Jan-2017 will use the 60000 Allowance, any Gross Pay on or after 1-Jan-2017 will use the 72000 Allowance.

Comment: You have $72,000.00 multiple times in the same table?  $8.25 each week and that's listed multiple times to? Where does `NIS` come from?  Why have a PAYE column in a table if it's calculated - better to have the base value and calculate on request.

Comment: Provide sample data as well as desired output. Why do you need a function - do you mean VBA? What have you attempted?

Comment: Please update the actual question with the sample data and additional information from your comments.  Put it all together in a better format and clarify what you need based on the questions asked.  That is how StackOverflow works... you continue to improve the question to get better answers.  Just as June7 already asked, please provide what you have tried and how you will use the output... in an query (i.e. SQL statement) or elsewhere in VBA.

Comment: The reason it is important to know the intended purpose and how you'll use the calculated results is that there can be more efficient methods of using joined and embedded SQL statements rather than executing individual queries within a VBA function.  This is especially true if you intend to perform calculations for multiple rows of data, for example in a report.  `DLookup()` is useful but not necessarily efficient.